# Can i separate data in a mysql row with "," and decipher that data?

Tags: php, mysql

Okay I am making a profile page where I will call on all of the user's information. Within the website users will gain points and earn badges. I have something like 35 badges. Rather than have a row in my users table for every badge(yes/no to decide whether user has earned badge) for every single user, I was wondering how I could do this without blowing up my users table.

I have a badge table with index, name, description, and photo. I was wondering can I make a single row in my users table for badges and separate badge numbers by  ",". Then decipher the badges so they all print on the page. I feel I can do this but don't know how.

Please help. Open to other suggestions

Comment: The most semantic way to do this is to make a user_badges table, then make a foreign key relationship with your users table. Put all earned badges into the user_badges table.

Answer (score 2):

You are describing a [many-to-many relationship](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29); use [a junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) to represent it.

Create a table of users and a table of badges. Then create a Users_Badges table with `user_id` and `badge_id` as foreign keys in it (together they will form a [composite key](http://www.sqa.org.uk/e-learning/MDBS01CD/page_19.htm)).

Answer (score 1):

you can create table structures like these.

**table structures**

**users**

userId
userName

**badges**

badgeId
badgeName

**user_badges**

userId
badgeID

**-- returns given users all badges within single row and comma seperated field.**

```
select group_concat(b.badgeName) as usersAllBadges
from user_badges ub
inner join users u on u.userId = ub.userId
inner join badges b on b.badgeId = ub.badgeID
where ub.userID=1
```

**-- returns given users all badges seperate rows.**

```
select b.badgeName
from user_badges ub
inner join users u on u.userId = ub.userId
inner join badges b on b.badgeId = ub.badgeID
where ub.userID=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You tagged php so I am assuming php

```
 explode(',',$data);
```

http://www.php.net